# any sort of getElement(s)By---- function for getting a class by name, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function getElsByClass(searchClass,node) {
        if ( node == null )
          node = document;
        var classElements = [],
            els = node.getElementsByTagName("div"),
            elsLen = els.length,
            pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)"), i, j;

        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
          if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
              classElements[j] = els[i];
              j++;
          }
        }
        return classElements;
    }

function getSong() {
    console.log("getSong ran");
    var songN = getElsByClass("info")[0], nmSong = getCookie();
    console.log(songN);
    songN = songN.getElementsByTagName("a");
    songN = songN[0].innerText + " - " + songN[1].innerText;
    if (nmSong != songN) {
        setCookie(songN);
    } else {
        setCookie(songN);
    }
    sendSong(songN);
    return songN;
}
setInterval(getSong(), 10000);
```

I've tried `songN = document.getElemenetsByClassName("info")`, and every combination I could find, and it will only run for maybe 30 seconds before it closes, I need it to run for hours, unattended...

I can run

```
var songN = getElsByClass("info")[0];
console.log(songN); //is actually defined when ran in Javascript Console in Chrome..
songN = songN.getElementsByTagName("a");
songN = songN[0].innerText + " - " + songN[1].innerText;
```

in Javascript console, and it returns exactly, what I'm trying to do, but if it runs as a userscript or after it's been injected into the web page, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined`, and I've tried to define it many different ways I found through searching google, and stackoverflow, I've ran the script on window.load, in the `<head>`, and tried to make it run in `<body>`.

`getElsByClass()` is my last attempt at it, it's not actually apart of my script, just a bit I tried from another script, tried shortening the name so it couldn't possibly conflict, but still nothing.

=== Update ===

Here is some more of the code..

```
function getCookie() {
    console.log("getCookie ran");
    var sname = "songname=", ca = document.cookie.split(';'), i = 0, c, t;
    for (i; i < ca.length; i++) {
        c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(sname) == 0) {
            t = c.substring(sname.length, c.length);
            console.log(t);
            return t;
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cvalue) {
    console.log("setCookie ran");
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 210000);//set it to expire in 3 minutes and 30 seconds from current time (this is average song time.)
    document.cookie = "songname=" + cvalue + "; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
}
```

Comment: First of all it would help if you described more what you are trying to do. This code is injected into some web page (music related I suppose) and should call sendSong for songs it finds?

Comment: I'm sure there are other problems, but some things that come to mind: setInterval takes the function as the first argument, but you are instead passing it the return value of the function.

Comment: Also you are probably setting a lot of cookies. Is there perhaps some limit on how many cookies you can set?

Comment: if (nmSong != songN) { seems unnecessary as it will just run the same setCookie(songN) regardless of the result.

Comment: the return bit was another test, and it returns the song, and I was trying to set it so when it ran every 10 seconds, it wouldn't send the song unless it was a different song than listed in the cookie, and it should be replacing the same cookie.. but I can't get to the rest of the script because it can't pull the song name from the page properly..

Comment: My **biggest** problem right now is that, `getSong()`, is not functioning properly... `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByClass`, anything I do to get the information inside of `<div class="info">`, returns as undefined, and thus the rest of it does not work..

Comment: problem solved.. tinkered with it for a bit, ultimately, the problem was it wasn't defining because script was running too soon, and fixed the loop by adding constant loop through multiple `songTimeout()` which is just `setTimeout((function(){getSong()}), 10000);`